# I get a "hostname in certificate didn't match" error when trying to connect to a Caddy website in my Android app

Tags: java, android, caddy, caddyfile

Good afternoon, as said in the title, I'm unable to connect to a subdomain on my caddy-powered website in my Android app. I'm migrating the backend of the app from Heroku to my own digitalocean droplet and the app used to work while it was using Heroku.

The error message I get is as follows:

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <sub.domain.com> != <domain.com> OR <domain.com>
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:185)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:114)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:95)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

The relevant Android code is:

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPostHC4 post = new HttpPostHC4(url);
    String json = "";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : valuePair.entrySet()) {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    UrlEncodedFormEntityHC4 entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntityHC4(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
    content = entity.getContent();
    System.out.println(entity);
    post.setEntity(entity);

    final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
    if (responseText != null) {
    System.out.println(responseText);
    }
}
```

And this is the relevant section of my Caddyfile

```
sub.domain.com {

    root /var/www/sub.domain.com/public
    log /var/www/sub.domain.com/storage/logs/caddy-access.log
    errors /var/www/sub.domain.com/storage/logs/caddy-error.log

    fastcgi / /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock php {
    index index.php
    }

    rewrite {
    r .*
    ext /
    to /index.php?{query}
    }

}
```

I can connect to the subdomain in my web browser, so I'm really not sure why this is happening. I'm not really too keen on disabling hostname verification, so I'm wondering if there's a way to fix it on the Caddy side.

Comment: try https://caddy.community/ you might get some more help there

Comment: Can you connect to domain.com in the browser?  What is the value of `url` in this line `final HttpPostHC4 post = new HttpPostHC4(url);`

Comment: @TobyAllen Hey, I was able to connect to domain.com with no problem in my browser. However, I eventually resolved the problem by using the okhttp library instead. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Maybe answer your own question with what you did (eg used a different library)

Comment: @TobyAllen Good idea, I just answered it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to resolve this problem by switching to the okhttp library.

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: '3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
}
```

New Version of Class:

```
/**
 * Created by luke on 8/29/2016.
 */

import android.net.Uri;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Request.Builder;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

public class HttpPostRequest {
    public static final MediaType JSON
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    InputStream content;
    String responseText;
    int code;

    HttpPostRequest(String url, Map<String, String> valuePair) {
    try {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);


        HttpUrl.Builder httpUrlBuilder = new HttpUrl.Builder();
        httpUrlBuilder.host(uri.getHost());
        httpUrlBuilder.scheme(uri.getScheme());

        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>(uri.getPathSegments());

        for (String path : paths) {
            httpUrlBuilder.addPathSegment(path);
        }

        Builder builder = new Request.Builder();

        FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : valuePair.entrySet()) {
            formBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        builder.url(httpUrlBuilder.build());
        builder.post(formBuilder.build());
        Response response = client.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
        code = response.code();
        responseText = response.body().string();
        responseText = responseText != null ? responseText : "";

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        if (responseText != null) {
            System.out.println(responseText);
        }
    }

    }
}
```